# How pass numpy array from Python to Golang function

Tags: python, numpy, go, ctypes

I'm trying  create library using with Golang for working in Python. But I have one problem: I can't pass numpy array to go function. Please, help me solve problem.

My code:

**main.go:**

```
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

type Matrix [][] int

//export Mass
func Mass(data Matrix) int {
  var sum int=0
  for i, x:= range data {
    for j, _ := range x {
        sum+=data[i][j]
    }
  }
  return sum
}

func main() {
}
```

**ex.py:**

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np

mysum = cdll.LoadLibrary(r'D:\tests\go\sum.dll')

array_2d_int = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=c_int32, ndim=2,
                                      flags='CONTIGUOUS')

def mass(a):
    mysum.Mass.argtypes = [array_2d_int]
    mysum.Mass.restype = c_int32
    return mysum.Mass(a)
```

**Compiling cmd-line:**

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o sum.dll main.go
```

When I call function from dll-library:

```
from ex import mass
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

print(mass(a))
```

I have errors:

```
unexpected fault address 0x1b216000
fatal error: fault
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x1b216000 pc=0x6ac92c1f]

goroutine 17 [running, locked to thread]:
....
```

Comment: The `Matrix` type is a go slice (in fact, it is a slice of slices).  This is a structure containing a data pointer, the length of the slice and the capacity of the slice.  The Python/numpy/ctypes wrapper doesn't know anything about that structure.  It passes just the data pointer to `Mass`, but the go function expects a slice structure.  You'll need to do some more work to make such an interface work.

Comment: @warren-weckesser, what can I read about this?

Comment: You could start with [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).  You could also consider making the argument to `Mass` a pointer to the data, possibly with additional arguments for the dimensions of the array.  But that means you are writing C-style code in go, and it would be preferable to write the go code using go's arrays and slices.  Perhaps a go guru will stop by with advice about passing C arrays to go functions.

Answer (score -2):

I dont know if this is what you are looking for.

1. Write the resulting numpy array to a file
2. Read the file in your go code

Execute the relevant commands in batch

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).